# Handle errors while downloading file on GWT button click

Tags: gwt, download, buttonclick

I have a requirement where I need to initiate file download from server on the click of a button. I am comfortable doing that. The point where I am stuck is incase there are errors
and the server sends an unsuccessful response, how do i handle that?

Regards,
Amar

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you download a file with 'Windows.open', try to wrap it in a try-catch block.

```
try {
   Window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8888/file.rar", "_self", "enabled");
} catch (Exception t) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Have you really tested it? I doubt it will throw any exception on HTTP status <> 200 series.